# How to get HOC in react to override props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

My props on an HOC do not seem to be overriding. I feel as though it might be the notation I'm using. Here is what I have right now.

```
export const HOCComponent = ({ someProp }) => (
  <ContainerComponent
    propOne={someValueOne}
    propTwo={someValueTwo}
    propThree={someValueThree)
  />
);

export const wrapperComponent = props =>(
  <HOCComponent {...props} propThree={someValueFour}/>
);
```

`someValueFour` does not seem to override `someValueThree`. Any suggestions would be super helpful! Thank you.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to if this is a HoC component or not. Generally you'd use HoC component like `HoC(Component)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap the order of the passed props such that anything you pass later overrides anything passed previously.

```
export const wrapperComponent = props =>(
  <HOCComponent propThree={someValueFour} {...props} />
);
```

The `HOCComponent` wrapper component needs to also pass along all props to the component it's wrapping.

```
export const HOCComponent = (props) => (
  <ContainerComponent
    propOne={someValueOne}
    propTwo={someValueTwo}
    propThree={someValueThree}
    {...props}
  />
);
```

Just a *minor* point about terminology, nothing in your code snippet is a Higher Order Component. HOCs consume a React component and return a new React Component.

An Example:

```
const withMyHOC = WrappedComponent => props => {
  // any HOC logic
  return (
    <Wrapper
      // <-- any wrapper props
    >
      <WrappedComponent
        {...props} // <-- pass props through
        // <-- override any props
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

usage:

```
export default withMyHOC(SomeComponent);
```

Comment: The second part of the answer was what I needed. Thanks for explaining the HOC. My containerComponent was an HOC but I guess it does count there.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you don't pass props from `HOCComponent` to `ContainerComponent` so `propThree` is not override. You need to pass `someProp` to `ContainerComponent`:

```
<ContainerComponent propOne propTwo propThree {...someProp} />
```